# Custom column in list

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Can any one tell me that, Is is possible in wss to have our custom column in a view of list. The way how we are adding edit and delete column in asp.net grid by setting autogenerateedit button property to true. I have to write my custom login on click event of that button. This action is going to be common for all list items.

Thanks 
Sachin K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that it is not possible out of the Box in SharePoint (WSS / MOSS). If you want to have such an option, you might need to create a Separate page that will have code to do the opertion. Try out the [SPGridView and SPDataSource](http://www.reversealchemy.net/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview/).

Else I would suggest (Recommend)  you to have a look at the **DataSheetView** option provided by the List, it will list List item details as all editable format, like Excel sheet.